# Running Django with Pyto on iPad

Tags: python-3.x, django, ipad

I am trying to build my first Webb app using Django. I’m using my iPad because I am on the move a lot. Anyways, I’m trying to follow Django’s instructions for building a poll application. I got the server running but when i made the changes that should have printed the Hello World but its now its giving me a ModuleNotFoundError.

I’ve tried copy and pasting the lines of code from Django’s website and I’ve tried to type it in on my own.

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'WellnessApp'

```
import os
`import sys
 def main():
"""Run administrative tasks."""
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'WellnessProject.settings')
try:
    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
except ImportError as exc:
    raise ImportError(
        "Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and "
        "available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you "
        "forget to activate a virtual environment?"
    ) from exc
execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)


  #if __name__ == '__main__':
  #    main()

if __name__ == '__main__':
  import background as bg
  with bg.BackgroundTask() as b:
     main()`
```